# Delete record from database

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, delete-row

I am trying unsuccessfully to delete a cell from a tableview and also delete its associated record from a database. Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.arr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.context save:&error];
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Please any suggestions are welcome. I have tried everything, read many similar questions on SO, still can't figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using core data?

Comment: You don't delete anything from a database. All you do it remove an object from an array. Also, do not call `reloadData` right after calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths...`.

Comment: The error is that the cell is removed but not the object...once I reload the table the cell reappears. @Abdullah yes

Comment: @pjv Once you actually delete the data from the database (before calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPath:`, there is no need to call `reloadData`. In fact, it will ruin the animation of the row deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you remove the objects in the array call:

```
NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [matchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[context deleteObject:eventToDelete];
```

Comment: @pjv As I said in my comment to the question, you weren't deleting the data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

For Deleting Row From Table View What you Have Written Is Correct but After Deleting Row Don't Call `ReloadData` after `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`....

```
[self.arr removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

You never deleted the object in the data-base.